# Using C++ threads with Android - AOSP build

Tags: multithreading, c++11, android-ndk, android-source, android.mk

I am writing an C++ application which is included as a part of Android OS (custom ROM). I am not able to use std::thread. Upon compiling the code I get "fatal error: 'thread' file not found". Compiler is not able to find include file 'thread'. Any way to fix this?

Comment: How do you build the application? What NDK version do you use? What compiler flags do you use?

Comment: Include the relevant pieces of your Android.mk and Application.mk?

Comment: I do not use NDK. The app is built along with AOSP during the OS make process. The toolchain that is used to build android is gcc 4.9.

Comment: Are you using std11 compiler features?, I mean did you specify std11 compiler flag in your makefile, cmake or others?

Comment: I did try -std=c++0x, -std=c++1x, -std=c++11. Nothing worked.

Comment: It would be best to share at least a snippet of the makefile. Sometimes the problem is a stupid tpyo

Comment: LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.cpp
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Wno-unused-parameter

LOCAL_MODULE := test

LOCAL_FORCE_STATIC_EXECUTABLE := true
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_ROOT_OUT)
LOCAL_UNSTRIPPED_PATH := $(TARGET_ROOT_OUT_UNSTRIPPED)

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := \
 libcutils \
 liblog \
 libc \
 libm

LOCAL_ADDITIONAL_DEPENDENCIES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/Android.mk

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

Comment: Did you try libstlport?

Comment: Yes. It did not work.